# Why this js code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js on 2 Model , but this is not working.

```
function AppViewModel1(Name) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(Name.fn);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(Name.ln);
}

function AppViewModel2(Name) {
    this.first = ko.observable(Name.fn);
    this.last = ko.observable(Name.ln);
}

 ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel1({ fn : "yahoo", ln: ".in" }));
 ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel2({ fn : "gmail", ln: ".com" }));
```

Can anybody please explain me, where i am wrong?

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect?

Comment: When i am trying to access the AppViewModel2 properties in html markup then its not bind it with object values

Comment: or at least show code you are using to access the model properties (i.e., the binding code in your html)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, Knockout only allows binding to a single view model.

A view model can contain references to other JS objects/classes, but only the one view model can be bound.

However, there is a plug-in available for binding multiple view models in Knockout:

https://github.com/hunterloftis/knockout.namespaces

Give it a look, and see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict what part of the dom your bindings are applying to. You can have multiple viewmodels bound on the same page/document, but they *cannot* overlap. So specify some IDs and restrict the binding to distinct parts of your page.

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example, `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))`. This restricts the activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

From [Knockout observables docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

Example:

```
function AppViewModel1(Name) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(Name.fn);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(Name.ln);
}

function AppViewModel2(Name) {
    this.first = ko.observable(Name.fn);
    this.last = ko.observable(Name.ln);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel1({ fn : "yahoo", ln: ".in" }),
    document.getElementById('gmailArea'));
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel2({ fn : "gmail", ln: ".com" }),
    document.getElementById('yahooArea'));
```

If you absolutely must have access to the same view model within the same parts of the page, then you're just going to have to merge it all together into one view model. Not pretty, but cest la vie.

For example

```
function AppViewModel1(Name) {
    this.gmailFirstName = ko.observable(Name.gmailFn);
    this.gmailLastName = ko.observable(Name.gmailLn);

    this.yFirst = ko.observable(Name.yFn);
    this.yLast = ko.observable(Name.yLn);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel1({ gmailFn: "google", gmialLn: ".com", yFn : "yahoo", yLn: ".in" }));
```

I've not used the namespace plulgin jimmym links, but it sounds intriguing.